# Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

write a simple Jenkins scripted pipeline. 
it should have 2 parameters(one checkbox, one textbox). 
include 2 stages in the pipeline, the first stage will be called based on whether the checkbox is check or not.

Answer (score 1):

A more targeted question I think would provide more benefit. However to directly answer your request:

```
#!groovy

properties([
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20')),
    parameters([
        booleanParam(name: 'CHECKBOX', defaultValue: true, description: 'Tick a checkbox'),
        string(name: 'STRING', defaultValue: 'stringhere', description: 'Enter a string'),
    ])
])

node {
    try {
        if (params.CHECKBOX) {
            stage('Stage 1') {
                //do something conditionally
                echo("${params.CHECKBOX}")
            }
        }
        stage('Stage 2') {
            // do someting else always
            echo(params.STRING)
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        // catch an error and do something else
        throw err
    }
    finally {
        // Finish with final mandatory tasks regardless of success/failure
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```

This starts off with Jenkins pipeline parameter syntax: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters
and using some basic pipeline steps: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/ such as `echo` and `shell`
interspersed with standard groovy for your conditional logic.